# Sql Query taking too long to execute in server , not in local

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an sql query to update a column through a count result from a view, this is my query

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Table]
   SET [ColumnName] = (select Count(View.Column) from View
                       where table.Column = View.ColumnN and View.Column1>0)                               
WHERE [dbo].[Table].Column in (select Column from View)
```

this query is taking 1 second when i execute it in my local SqlServer but when i executed in the server where the application is deployed it takes about 1.36 minute , is there something wrong i'm doing :)
Thnks in advance

Comment: You shouldn't handle such values manually anyway. Either have a view, or computed column, or use triggers to manage the column.

Comment: The fact that you call an object `VIEW` could mean that it's due to a poorly written `VIEW`, which we don't have the DDL for.

Comment: I also agree, aggregates shouldn't be stored when they can be calculated. This certainly appears to be one of those times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's common. Sometimes records from 10 to 100 will cause efficiency loss apparently. Try to group first then use join to combine update records. Your columns relation is not clear for me, just for reference.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Table]
   SET [ColumnName] = d.Result
FROM (SELECT View.ColumnN, COUNT(View.Column) AS Result
      FROM View
      WHERE View.Column1 > 0
      GROUP BY View.ColumnN 
     ) d INNER JOIN
     [dbo].[Table] t
     ON d.ColumnN = t.Column
```

Comment: thnks for your support